# MDX Calculated member filter by dimension attributes

Tags: ssas, mdx, dimensions

I would like to create a calculation in my SSAS Cube and filter a measure by several dimensions.

With a filter on one dimension it works like this:

```
(
    [Employee categorie].[description].&[local management], 
    [Employee categorie].[description].&[topmanagement], 
    [Measures].[Count]
)
```

But how can I include a filter on a second dimension?

```
[retirement].[description].&[partial early retirement]
```

This is the functional background:
I would like to have from the total of headcount only the managers who are in partial early retirement.
This is just one example from several task I have to solve.

Comment: Does that tuple in your first snippet actually work? - doesn't look valid mdx to me

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't look like a valid tuple to me as you have two members of the same hierarchy in it:

```
(
    [Employee categorie].[description].&[local management], 
    [Employee categorie].[description].&[topmanagement], 
    [Measures].[Count]
)
```

This is ok:

```
(
    [Employee categorie].[description].&[local management], 
    [retirement].[description].&[partial early retirement], 
    [Measures].[Count]
)
```

You could add two tuples with the same dimensionality like this:

```
(
    [Employee categorie].[description].&[local management], 
    [retirement].[description].&[partial early retirement], 
    [Measures].[Count]
)
 +
(
    [Employee categorie].[description].&[topmanagement], 
    [retirement].[description].&[partial early retirement], 
    [Measures].[Count]
)
```